# Using str_extract_all to extract only first two words in R?

Tags: r, regex, vector, subset

I am stuck with a problem which should be simple. Likely a regex issue. I am a newbie. Please consider a string vector such as the one:

```
species_location<-c('Homo_sapiens_Lausanne_Switzerland', 'Solenopsis_invicta_California_US', 'Rattus_novaborensis_Copenhagen_Denmark', 'Candida_albicans_Crotch_Home')
```

I wanted to end up with a new vector for species that looks like:

```
c(Homo_sapiens, Solenopsis_invicta, Rattus_novaborensis, Candida_albicans)
```

Currently I am using the following function:

```
str_extract_all(species_location,'^(\\S+?)_(\\S+?)_')
```

However it returns the first 3 words instead of what I designed it for. I cannot figure out why. Please could anyone help and explain? Thanks

UPDATE: 
For anyone passing by, the code entered above works as it should, excepting on my R Console for Mac OS 3.0.0, R.app 1.60. I still do not know what is the issue there but it might be interest someone else to check. Will try and add a picture here. [image: Unusual interpretation of regex]

Comment: I can't reproduce this, running your example code I get the first two words of each item (followed by a trailing `_`). Are you sure your example code matches what you've been running?

Comment: If you want to be positive you're not going crazy - and suspect that there could be some sort of magic happening with your lazy modifier, then try this: `^([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+)_`

Comment: This is very weird!! On my side it returns the first three words every time, I have tried so many small modifications (e.g. using {2})!..

Comment: BTW I use an old MacBook, R Console 3.0.0  --- I have just tried on a new Lenovo from a friend on RGui 3.3.2 and like you guys say there the code works! Why?.. Anyways, thanks for a new regex (I am new to this) @Addison -- yours works on both computers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just relying on the `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)

species_location<-c('Homo_sapiens_Lausanne_Switzerland', 'Solenopsis_invicta_California_US', 'Rattus_novaborensis_Copenhagen_Denmark', 'Candida_albicans_Crotch_Home')

word(species_location, 1,2, sep="_")
```

Comment: In the end apparently there is some R version behavior issue, see above. Still I am marking yours as the best solution as the code is so much cleaner, which will be easier for me to understand later.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `str_extract`

```
str_extract(species_location, "[^_]+_[^_]+")
```